# Having trouble understanding this context in Array.map callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have the following snippet in a React component. This is a trivial example, but I'm trying to better my understanding of the `this` keyword and its context

```
const NAVBAR_ITEM_TITLES = ["Home", "About", "Contact"];

function makeNavbarItems() {
  return NAVBAR_ITEM_TITLES.map(item => ({
    title: item,
    handleButtonClick() {
      console.log(`clicked the ${this.title} button`);
    },
  }));
}

const Navbar = () => {
  const navbarItems = makeNavbarItems();

  return (
    <>
      {navbarItems.map(item => (
        <div>
          <button key={item.title} onClick={item.handleButtonClick}>
            {item.title}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

I wrote  a small function that returns some anonymous objects to populate a navbar. However, the `this` context inside the anonymous object that `map` returns is undefined. I understand that if I create a named object like `myObj` then I may access the title property such as `myObj.title`, but I'd like to gain understanding of what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Cheers.

Comment: From your code, it's working fine. `undefined` value only comes when you try to use an arrow function `() => {}`. That will be helpful if you can share how you call `handleButtonClick`

Comment: @NickVu sure, just updated with the full component.

Comment: One of the great things about function components in React, is that you never need to use `this` and its complicated behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have access to the `item` string, which you're aliasing it as `title`: there is no need to use `this` at all:

```
function makeNavbarItems() {
  return NAVBAR_ITEM_TITLES.map(item => ({
    title: item,
    handleButtonClick() {
      console.log(`clicked the ${item} button`);
    },
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` always refer to the object in the current context, and in this case, the new object you are creating with your prototype. As @Terry said, it's not really necessary here. In some case, you will need `this` to differentiate between two expression with the same name but on different scope. (e.g. A global variable and a local one of the same name).